# Simple C text scanning and printing

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf, text-editor

I am writing a very simple editor. I have it so that the program reads from stdin and then prints to stdout right now (see code below). I want a program that will take in a file, and then depending on the command either print or append more text to the file. I am still confused how to do this after reading related questions. Do I use both scanf to read the file and then printf to print into the same file? Any clarification is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINES 10

char text[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINES];


int main(void){
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    //check for file
    if(infile==NULL){
        puts("Error--no file found");
        }


    int count, x, y;
    printf("Enter to quit the program.\n");

    for(count=1; count<MAX_LINES+1; count++){
        printf("%d: ", count);
        fgets(text[count], MAX_LINES, stdin);

    }

    for(x=0; x<count; x++){
        for(y=0;text[x][y];y++){
            putchar(text[x][y]);}
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
 //end program
}
```

Comment: Almost all editors open a temp file for writing then unlink the old file and rename the temp file when they close it.

Comment: Since `scanf()` doesn't care about white space but people editing files do, you're unlikely to be able to use `scanf()`.  (Yes, you can work around even that, but it is hard work and not really rewarding.)  Your code shows you using `fgets()`, a much more sensible option.  You need to separate the number of lines from the maximum width of a line.  You might need to think about POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) for the input since it handles arbitrarily long lines.  You open "`infile`" for writing only, and actually read from `stdin`.

Comment: Is there a way to both read from infile and add the text to infile? (instead of stdout?)

Comment: @SarahMarkers you open infile in write mode, so you can also write to it. You might need to use `fseek()` to move to the position in the file where you want to write. You can write with functions like `fputs`, `fputc`, `fprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not "read from `stdin`", it reads from a named file, but, does not write to that file.

And here is another confusion

```
char text[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINES];
```

This would be better as

```
#define MAX_LINES   10
#define MAX_LENGTH  1000
...
char text[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH];
```

Next, look at this loop

```
for(count=1; count<MAX_LINES+1; count++)
```

This will ignore the 0th element of the array and go out of bounds with the last. It should be

```
for(count=0; count<MAX_LINES; count++)
```

This is for `stdin`, but if the file is an opened disk file, say `infile` you should check if the read hits the end of the file

```
fgets(text[count], MAX_LINES, infile);
```

and replace with with

```
if (fgets(text[count], MAX_LENGTH, infile) == NULL)
    break;
```

Your commented question *Is there a way to both read from infile and add the text to infile?* Yes but it's unviable, as @JonathanLeffler wrote *"prepare a new file first"*.

Comment: OK, cool. So I made those changes, and now I am still a bit confused. Now the text editor will not let me enter text in. is there a way to prepare the infile, then use stdin to write to the file?